# when i redirect http to https it gives 500 internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When I redirect http to https by using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

it gives 500 internal server error.

> /home/siggle/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command
>   '\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module
>   not included in the server configuration

Comment: Perhaps `mod-rewrite` isn't enabled on your server. You can use `AllowOverride All` in your server config file or Ask your hosting service provider to enable it for you.

Comment: ok i'll try thanks

Comment: how to set AllowOverride All - hosting service provider says the httpd.conf file not accessible to shared hosting! and do it in htaccess says when i add this in htaccess ErrorDocument 404 /404-page.html
<filesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)$">
ErrorDocument 404 /404-image.jpg 
</filesMatch> the problem persist! please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to install URL-rewrite module on your server:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite